# Using Xamarin library from iPhone native application

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

I'd like to compile some computational C# code into an iOS/iPhone native lib that can be used by native iPhone applications. I have Xamarin and I do not own a Mac.

I'm not very familiar With iPhone Development or Objective C. I'm thinking since Xamarin compiles to native library then it may boil down to exposing some methods and creating some header files?

1. Is this possible?
2. How? (If you do not have a full answer then maybe you hve some pointers/ideas can help me on my way.)
3. Is there any way to compile my library for iPhone under Windows/Linux, or do I have to purchase a Mac?

Comment: No, you can't. See this [question][1] (and Rolf's answer for why).


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12365504/220643

Answer (score 1):

After having tried the pain of not using a Mac for iPhone development I advise that the only way to make sense of it is to buy a cheap Mac mini, even a second-hand one will do, then install MonoDevelop, Xamarin MonoTouch and XCode.

The expensive bits are the Mac which is about 600 bucks new or a lot less second hand and the pro license for the Xamarin tools.

The upside is that you get a Mac which for *some things* beats the crap out of a PC.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Xamarin's MonoTouch is only available for Mac, so I do not believe it is possible.

The only way to compile any iPhone libraries or applications on a windows / linux box is to set up an iphone toolchain. (see http://code.google.com/p/iphone-dev/wiki/Building)

Once you set up the toolchain, it might be possible to integrate Xamarin somehow into this toolchain, but I absolutely do not know how to do this. Moreover, you would not have any kind of IDE with a toolchain.

So I think it would be much easier to buy a mac and install Xamarin with MonoDevelop.